# Generating NBA play by plays per quarter

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to generate NBA play-by-plays per quarter.

How I did this was picking the number of points one team will score in a quarter, and then generating plays to meet those number of points.

So let's say I pick Team A to score 5 points in a quarter. I made an algorithm to generate this example list:

[ ['2 pointer','SWITCH'], ['MISSED 2 pointer', 'Offensive Rebound', 'STAY'], ['3 pointer', 'SWITCH']]

(This list is a lot simpler than what is actually generated. I have added more features like assists and rebounds, except for steals and turnovers.)

'SWITCH' means to switch possessions, while 'STAY' means the current team keeps possession. Every 'SWITCH' needs to have at least one action available in the other team's list, while every 'STAY' needs to have at least one action available in the current team's list.

Now, when I create two lists for 2 different teams, their lists may differ in length because (among other things) one team may score more than the other.

When I try to join the two lists together to create play-by-play simulations, this can result in one team being empty of actions when there are 'SWITCH's on the other team.

My question is how can I add extra 'SWITCH's or 'STAY's to any teams list so that every 'SWITCH' will have an action on the other team's list and every 'STAY' will have an action in the current team's list.

My first thought was to add random turnovers and steals (resulting in a 'SWITCH') in the lists and hope it will work, but I can't think of a way to go about this.

Also, the order of the initial team's list don't matter as long as the list meets the number of required scoring points.

This is what I have so far:

> 

def join_steals_tov(teamA_list, teamB_list):

```
overall_list = []

possession = 'Team A'

print(len(teamA_list))
print(len(teamB_list))

while teamA_list and teamB_list:
    
    if possession == 'Team A':
        play = teamA_list.pop(0)
        play.insert(0,'Team A')
        overall_list.append(play)
        print(f"Team A: {play}")
        
        if play[-1] == 'SWITCH':
            possession = 'Team B'
    else:
        play = teamB_list.pop(0)
        play.insert(0,'Team B')
        overall_list.append(play)
        print(f"Team B: {play}")
        
        if play[-1] == 'SWITCH':
            possession = 'Team A'
    
return teamA_list, teamB_list, overall_list
```

Comment: Does it matter how much the other team scores? Or you just trying to generate play by play for the 1 team?

Comment: Yes. So initially, I'm creating two lists for two separate teams. One list will add up to however many points I set it to. So one list will add up to 20 points for example, meaning that team corresponding to that list will score 20 points. Then, I am trying to merge those 2 lists together to form play-by-play data.

Comment: I'm thinking I can randomly add turnovers and steals in each list, but 1) I don't know how it would work 2) doing that might just make it more complex. Maybe I can't start with required number of points? I'm pretty stuck right now

Comment: Ok I’ll give it a think. There’s a few ways I’m thinking you could do it using probabilities to create those random events.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach to generating a play-by-play list for a quarter, starting with two lists of scoring events, e.g.

```
teamA_scores = ['A2', 'A3']          
teamB_scores = ['B3', 'B3', 'B2']
```

Step 1: combine the lists into a single list, and shuffle the combined list, e.g.

```
scores: ['A3', 'B3', 'A2', 'B3', 'B2']
          ^^ --- team A scores 3 points
```

Step 2: When the same team scores twice in a row, there must be a non-scoring event by the other team. So create a new list of plays that includes those mandatory SWITCH plays, e.g.

```
switch: ['A3', 'B3', 'A2', 'B3', 'AS', 'B2']
                                  ^^ --- team A gives the ball back to team B without scoring
```

Step 3: Add an end-of-quarter play to the list (just to make the next step easier), e.g.

```
end Q:  ['A3', 'B3', 'A2', 'B3', 'AS', 'B2', 'AQ']
                                              ^^ --- time runs out with team A in possession
```

Step 4: Now add some additional non-scoring plays to fill out the quarter. In the sample code, the list of plays is padded out to an arbitrary length of 10. For realism, you would need to assign a time to each play, and pad the list until the total time is 12 minutes.

```
plays:  ['AK', 'A3', 'B3', 'AS', 'BS', 'A2', 'B3', 'AS', 'B2', 'AQ']
          ^^ --- team A keeps the ball, e.g. missed shot, offensive rebound
                            ^^ --- team A loses the ball
                                  ^^ --- team B loses the ball
```

Here's some sample code that shows how it all comes together to create list of 10 plays from two lists of scoring plays:

```
from random import shuffle
from random import randrange
from random import randint

# helper functions
def getTeam(event):
    return event[0]

def makeSameTeamItem(event, item):
    if getTeam(event) == 'A':
        return 'A' + item
    else:
        return 'B' + item

def makeOtherTeamItem(event, item):
    if getTeam(event) == 'B':
        return 'A' + item
    else:
        return 'B' + item

# start with a list of scores for each team
teamA_scores = ['A2', 'A3']
teamB_scores = ['B3', 'B3', 'B2']

# step 1: combine and shuffle to create an overall list of scores
scores = teamA_scores + teamB_scores
shuffle(scores)
print 'scores:', scores

# step 2: create list of plays including mandatory SWITCH plays
plays = []
plays.append(scores[0])
for i in range(1, len(scores)):
   if getTeam(scores[i]) == getTeam(scores[i-1]):
      plays.append(makeOtherTeamItem(scores[i], 'S'))
   plays.append(scores[i])
print 'switch:', plays

# step 3: add the end of quarter play
plays.append(makeOtherTeamItem(scores[-1], 'Q'))
print 'end Q: ', plays

# step 4: insert additional non-scoring plays to fill the quarter
quarter = 10
while len(plays) < quarter:
   index = randrange(0, len(plays))
   if quarter - len(plays) == 1 or randint(1,2) == 1:
      plays.insert(index, makeSameTeamItem(plays[index], 'K'))
   else:
      plays.insert(index, makeOtherTeamItem(plays[index], 'S'))
      plays.insert(index, makeOtherTeamItem(plays[index], 'S'))
print 'plays: ', plays
```

Comment: This is great approach. To get the scoring events down first, and then fill out consecutive scoring events by the same team with non-scoring plays. It wasn't in my question, but what if I am also trying to add a "narrow range" of a certain non-scoring event? For example, if NBA teams make 50% of their 2 pointers, the number of missed 2 pointers must be "roughly" (give or take 1 or 2) the same number of 2 pointers made. And how can I further add on assists, offensive rebounds, defensive rebounds? I will try to solve this myself starting from your approach, so I'll keep this updated, but if you

Comment: (continued...) have an idea on how to do so before I figure it out, that would be great!

Comment: @theyeinkye It's easy if there are a lot of non-scoring events in the list. For example, if there are ten 'A2' events and twenty non-scoring events ('AS' or 'AK'), then you could randomly select between 9 and 11 non-scoring events, and convert them to 'AM2' events (team A misses 2 pointer). You'd have to do the same thing for 3 pointers. The rest of the 'AS' and 'AK' get converted to ball out of bounds, blocked shots, takeaways, offensive penalties, etc.

Comment: That's a good idea to split up the events between scoring and non-scoring and partition them accordingly to event percentages. I'll give that a try, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good way to play with Markov Chains. Take a look [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/markov-chains-python-tutorial)

The basic idea is that for each Current State, there is a probability of moving into a Next State. You can create a probability matrix of what the current state is, and the probability of what the next state could be. Then use those weights to pull from the `random.choices`. You can make it as complex as you'd like. Key is to start simple, get it to work, then you can add more and embellish it (for example I was going to add the states of a 3 point missed and 3 point made, ( you'd also have to then have to include probability of 2 point missed, 2 point made...or you could have that as an extension of shot missed, and shot made), but figured I'll leave that to you to work with and add in there. You could also add in there offensive and defensive fouls, if it was a defensive shooting foul, probability of if shot made had an assist, etc.)

It's just a matter then of setting up a few functions to keep track of everything and "play" out the possession.

So here's my example:

**1. Create the probability matrix for each team. Index will be Curent State, and Columns are Next State.**

**Note: you want each rows' sum to be 1**

```
import pandas as pd
import random

prob_matrix_A = pd.DataFrame([
[0, 0.05,   0.1,    0.375,  0.475,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0.02,   0,  0,  0,  0.19,   0.79,   0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
columns = ['Possession', 'Unforced Turnover','Steal','Miss Shot','Made Shot','Off Reb','Def Rebound', 'Change Possession'],
index = ['Possession', 'Unforced Turnover','Steal','Miss Shot','Made Shot','Off Reb','Def Rebound', 'Change Possession'])


prob_matrix_B = pd.DataFrame([
[0, 0.05,   0.1,    0.475,  0.375,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0.02,   0,  0,  0,  0.09,   0.89,   0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
columns = ['Possession', 'Unforced Turnover','Steal','Miss Shot','Made Shot','Off Reb','Def Rebound', 'Change Possession'],
index = ['Possession', 'Unforced Turnover','Steal','Miss Shot','Made Shot','Off Reb','Def Rebound', 'Change Possession'])
```

So here's the probability matrix for Team A:

```
print (prob_matrix_A.to_string())
                   Possession  Unforced Turnover  Steal  Miss Shot  Made Shot  Off Reb  Def Rebound  Change Possession
Possession                  0               0.05    0.1      0.375      0.475     0.00         0.00                  0
Unforced Turnover           0               0.00    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.00         0.00                  1
Steal                       0               0.00    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.00         0.00                  1
Miss Shot                   0               0.02    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.19         0.79                  0
Made Shot                   0               0.00    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.00         0.00                  1
Off Reb                     1               0.00    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.00         0.00                  0
Def Rebound                 0               0.00    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.00         0.00                  1
Change Possession           0               0.00    0.0      0.000      0.000     0.00         0.00                  0
```

**2. Set up how to keep track of score and which team has the ball:**

```
team_score_limit = 25


# game setup
game_dict = {'team_a':{'score':0, 'possession':False, 'prob_matrix': prob_matrix_A},
             'team_b':{'score':0, 'possession':False, 'prob_matrix': prob_matrix_B},
             'score_limit':team_score_limit}

# Do a jump ball to see who starts with ball
# Lets say team_a has 55% of getting the jump, and team_b 45%
wins_jump = random.choices(['team_a','team_b'], weights=[.55,.45], k=1)[0]
game_dict[wins_jump]['possession'] = True
print('%s: Wins the jump ball' %wins_jump)
```

**3. Create the functions to determine who has possession (Ie. who is on offense, defense):**

```
# Function to return who has possession
def possession(game_dict):
    for k, v in game_dict.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            if v['possession'] == True:
                offense_team = k
            if v['possession'] == False:
                defense_team = k
    return offense_team, defense_team
```

**4. Create the function to play out the possession based on the probabilities:**

```
def play(current_state, game_dict):
    # Determine who has possession and get their prob matrix
    offense, defense = possession(game_dict)
    prob_matrix = game_dict[offense]['prob_matrix']
    states_list = prob_matrix.columns.tolist()
    weights = prob_matrix.loc[current_state,:].tolist()
    
    # Based on current state weights, get the next state
    new_state = random.choices(states_list, weights=weights, k=1)[0]
    
    if 'Possession' not in new_state:
        if new_state in ['Def Rebound', 'Steal']:
            print ('%s: %s by %s' %(offense, new_state, defense))
        else:
            print ('%s: %s' %(offense, new_state))
    current_state = new_state
    

    if current_state == 'Made Shot':
        game_dict[offense]['score'] += 2
        
        # if team_a score reached the limit, we'll return False to stop the game
        if game_dict['team_a']['score'] >= game_dict['score_limit']:
            return False
 
    # if it's a change of possession, we'll update our game_dict
    if new_state == 'Change Possession':
        game_dict[offense]['possession'] = False
        game_dict[defense]['possession'] = True
    
    # else the team who currently possess the ball didn't change from the previous outcome (Ie. Offensive rebound), then they get another possession play 
    else:
        play(current_state, game_dict)
```

**5. Set the initial `current_state` to start the "game" and play it out:**

```
# Play the first quarter 
current_state = 'Possession'   
continue_play = True   
while continue_play != False:    
    continue_play = play(current_state, game_dict)    
    
    
    
print ('\nEnd of 1st Quarter!\n')
print ('**************************')
print ('team_a: %s\tteam_b: %s' %(game_dict['team_a']['score'],game_dict['team_b']['score']))
```

**Output:**

```
runfile('test.py', wdir='C:/test')
team_a: Wins the jump ball
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Off Reb
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Miss Shot
team_a: Def Rebound by team_b
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Steal by team_b
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Miss Shot
team_a: Def Rebound by team_b
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Miss Shot
team_a: Def Rebound by team_b
team_b: Steal by team_a
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Steal by team_a
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Unforced Turnover
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Steal by team_b
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Unforced Turnover
team_b: Steal by team_a
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Unforced Turnover
team_a: Miss Shot
team_a: Off Reb
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Made Shot
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Miss Shot
team_a: Off Reb
team_a: Made Shot
team_b: Miss Shot
team_b: Def Rebound by team_a
team_a: Made Shot

End of 1st Quarter!

**************************
team_a: 26      team_b: 16
```